# Multisite config directories of subsides

Tags: 8, configuration

I set up a local Drupal 8 multisite, using Acquia dev desktop. It's working fine. I added all Drupal 8 core files to my local repository and pushed them to a central remote repository.

- in `sites/default/settings.php` I added
  `$config_directories['staging'] = 'sites/default/config/staging';`to
  make the configuration directory versionable.
- All sites (main site, subside1 and subside2) has different databases

But what about the `sites/subside1/` and `sites/subside2/` config files? Do I have to add also a different path for those files? Do those have to be versioned or not?

I want to clone my repo to make instances of this multisite for staging and live environments.

Comment: You can have a configuration directory per site per environment. Or only per environment. Or only per site.

Comment: I have one default site (site 1) and to other sites (site 2) and (site 3). They are 3 different sites but with the same kind of template. What do you for `$config_directories` ?

Comment: It's up to you. You can have it either way.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit up to you how you manage your config. In my multisites I have a `../config` directory outside the web root. Each site instance then has it's own folder in there. And inside each one I split the config per environment.

`shared/` holds the config that is similar on all environments. `local/` holds all the extra config for local development. And `live/` holds the extra config for the live site. This can be achieved using the [Config Split](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_split) module.

```
project/
├── config/
│   ├── bar/
│   │   ├── live/
│   │   ├── local/           
│   │   └── shared/
│   └── foo/
│       ├── live/
│       ├── local/
│       └── shared/
└── web/
    └── sites/
        ├── bar/
        └── foo/
```

The `settings.php` config for the `foo/` instance then looks like this:

```
$config_directories['sync'] = '../config/foo/shared';
```

And the Git-ignored `settings.local.php` on my local machine looks like this:

```
$config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = TRUE;
$config['config_split.config_split.live']['status'] = FALSE;
```

Whereas on the live server it looks like this:

```
$config['config_split.config_split.local']['status'] = FALSE;
$config['config_split.config_split.live']['status'] = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are okay with the configs for the subsites mixing with the default site then you can set the config directory to be the same as is in `default/settings.php` by adding to the `sites/subsite1/settings.php` and `sites/subsite2/settings.php`

```
$config_directories['sync'] = '../config/sync';
```

(relative to the site root, not subsite root)

if you want to manage the subsite configs completely separate from the default site then you could in theory set these unique to each site - so in `sites/subsite1/settings.php`

```
$config_directories['sync'] = '../config/subsite1_sync';
```

... this possibly might be more problematic since you now have as many discrete configs as you do subsites, but it depends on what config settings you need to sync I suppose.

this is also explained more by @[AjitS](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/6461/ajits) here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/271321/91863 - where it is also recommended to explore the `config_split` and `config_filter` contrib modules